# What does the symbol ≪ mean in word origin description in dictionary.com?

Tags: etymology, symbols

What is the meaning of the symbol ≪ in word origin description in dictionary.com?

e.g. in https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ule

> ORIGIN OF -ULE
>   < French < Latin -ulus, -ula, -ulum diminutive formative with nouns of the 1st and 2nd declensions ≪ *-el- (cf. -cle1, -elle, -ole1); the deverbal suffix -ulus, etc. (cf. cingulum, tumulus) is of distinct orig.

[Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:dictionary.com%20%E2%89%AA) for more examples.

Is this symbol common among many dictionaries?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the in-house symbolism of an arbitrary work.

Comment: It's not super common but rather trivial. I might've come up with it myself and have seen it in informal forum posts too, once or twice, that is "<<". It's obviously from deleting an unreliable intermediate reconstruction. The arrow notation is discuraged in running text anyways, Ihear. On second thought, I think I seen it in etymological dictionaries' lists of symbols, too, but can't remember where. This question belongs on linguistics.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<< means that one or more links in the etymological chain are supposed but are unattested.

Compare:

x < y means that x is believed to come from y immediately.

x << y means that x is believed to come from y though not immediately, that is, one or more words mediate between x and y but that word or those words have not been identified.

x (<?) < y means that that x is believed to come from y though it is not known whether it does so immediately OR one or more words mediate between x and y.

Comment: Good! Do you have any reference about this? I can not find it in the website.